# Muirhead's Inequality (software?)

Tags: reference-request, inequality, computer-algebra-systems

I just started learning about inequalities: Schur's, Karamata's, Muirhead's, etc... They are beautiful but it seems that in the case of more than two variables, some of the computations become a nightmare. **If you work with inequalities, do you suggest any particular software package?** I looked at Maple and Mathematica but was not able to find *an implementation of the symmetric sum* (perhaps the nomenclature is different?)